# Pandas to_datetime transformation, format with dots

Tags: python, pandas, date

I want to aggregate rows with time data which were measured every minute to rows summing up the data for hours/days. I'm using the pandas resample method for that.  Beforehand I need to convert the data type of the column containg the timestamp from object to datetime.

I'm using the pandas to_datetime()-Method for that with the following line of code:

`df_resampled['DateTime'] =  pd.to_datetime(df_resampled['DateTime'], format="%d.%m.%y %H:%M")`

Here I always get the error: "**time data '03.11.2020 15:34' does not match format '%d.%m.%y %H:%M' (match)**"

I don't really understand why I get this error since the timestamp has the format "day.month.year hour:minute"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Y` (with a capital) for the YYYY format with century, see [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) documentation:

| Directive | Meaning | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| %y | Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number. | 00, 01, …, 99 |
| %Y | Year with century as a decimal number. | 0001, 0002, …, 2013, 2014, …, 9998, 9999 |

```
df_resampled['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_resampled['DateTime'],
                                          format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
```